# How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL but with a different table?

Tags: sql

How do I do this

[How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

but with a different table?  Table A has the date and table C has the ID I want to be distinct.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [tour] and also read [ask] to get better answers for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

use join for that two table and then use distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY statement instead of distinct for this.

```
SELECT t1.a, MAX(t2.a)
FROM t1
JOIN t2
    ON T1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY T1.a
```